# REST, avoid redundancy in urls

Tags: rest, url, split

What's the best practice in order to avoid redundancy in url writing for REST Services ? 
For instance, let's say that I have an user, this user can post questions and some answers can be related to this question. What I'm doing is :

```
/users : List of all users
/users/1234 : Description of user with id = 1234
/users/1234/questions : List of questions asked by this user
/users/1234/questions/5678 : Question identified by id = 5678 asked by user 1234
/users/1234/questions/5678/answers : Answers of this questions
/users/1234/questions/5678/answers/1111 : Answer 1111 of question 5678 asked by user 1234
```

And so on ...

The thing is that I also have those endpoints :

```
/questions/5678 : Question with id = 5678
/questions/5678/answers
/questions/5678/answers/1111
...
```

I remember that any item must have an unique accessor in order to comply with RESTful best practices so, what's the best solution ?

I found the second way more elegant and only have :

```
/users/AAAA/
/users/AAAA/questions
/questions/XXXX
/questions/XXXX/answers
/answers/YYYY
```

But in terms of performances (I'm working on a mobile application), It's not the best. Why ? Because this request :

```
/users/1234/questions/5678/answers/1111
```

Would be splitted in more request which means bigger bandwidth usage.

So, what is the best "pattern" to do so ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /users/{userId}
GET /questions/{questionId}
GET /questions?userId={userId}
GET /answers?userId={userId}&questionId={questionId}
```

In the real world, that solution might not be adequate, but this is clearly homework, so it should be fine.